# Android: Native Camera Application default to Front Camera

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I managed to have the camera to use Front camera by default when using intent for Android api 21 below using below code:

```
intent.putExtra(
    "android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING",
    Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
```

I am wonder how to set to front facing for android API 21 above. The above won't work.

Answer (score 0):

To use camera for api 21+ (let say api 23 or Android M), you need to use the latest **PermissionManager** to ask user to grant camera permission. Without the camera permission, you can not access the camera.

Below is the sample code to check and request for camera permission if permissio has not granted:

```
if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
            MY_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

After requesting permission dialog to user, you can check the response on `onRequestPermissionResult` function of the calling activity:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == MY_REQUEST__CODE) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Now user should be able to use camera
        }
        else {
            // Your app will not have this permission. Turn off all functions 
            // that require this permission or it will force close like your 
            // original question
        }
    }
}
```

Official doc: http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html

Comment: He calls Camera app, passing extras in intent. How your answer is related to that?

Comment: Yes, even calling intent to access camera requires permission for api 23+

Comment: Api 23 also counts in api 21+. I gave OP an idea how to work with latest api. Maybe it will be useful for OP.